# Cypress loads blank page on attempt to open test app url

Tags: automation, cypress

On attempt to open simple app url in primitive Cypress (10.11) test (via Chrome browser)  - blank page is loaded

cypress.config.js

```
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");

module.exports = defineConfig({
   chromeWebSecurity: false,
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      // implement node event listeners here
    },
    "viewportWidth":1980,
    "viewportHeight":1020,
    "screenshotsFolder": "mochawesome-report/assets",
    "videosFolder": "mochawesome-report/assets",
     baseUrl: 'http://power-inspiration-1088-dev-ed.scratch.my.site.com/ebikes',
  },
});
```

login.cy.js

```
describe('Sales Force First Test', () => {
  it('Open page', () => {
    cy.visit('/')
  })
})
```

On attempt to open the same url in non-automation-controlled Chrome content is loaded. Firefox browser works perfectly for that site with Cypress (i.e. page content is loaded and rendered properly)

Comment: Does the site have some sort of service worker?

Comment: It's hard to say. Basically used Salesforce Sandbox  for app deployment https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/quick-start-ebikes-sample-app/deploy-app-ebike. And tried to implement really basic test via Cypress

Answer (score 0):

For now, it works only in Firefox. Cypress team is working on this spike to resolve this issue - https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/24290